# Highlight a view when softkeybord is out

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

I've this goal to achive.

[image]

Notice how the selected view (insde there's an edittext and a textView) is highlighted to show where focus is.

Now I reach this point

[image]

The views to "select" are inside an ListView.
The transparent grey is given to a GestureLayout that cover the entire screen.

I've no ideas how can I achive this.

Answer (score -2):

To detect the focus or any activity on that view you can check this:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            //put your highlight code here
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```